# Tips to position some div with image in my page

Tags: jquery, css, html

I would like to create a webpage which contains images like this :

[image]

What is the best way to position each `<div>` in my page ? Use column ? Or a `position:fixed` ?

Comment: I advise you this list (http://codegeekz.com/jquery-grids/) of plugins to create what you want to do, and they are also responsive

Comment: Yes, you can use jQuery, I think it is the best way but if you want to do this by yourself, I think you can crop the images and use columns, it is the simplest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's static and you do not care about reponsivness you can use a div with relative position, and inside each picture with a div with absolute position, placing then wherever you want.

Now if you do care about responsivness you can use a plugin-in such as:

- [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html)
- [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)
- [codecanyonplugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/final-tiles-grid-gallery/4734090)